# Excel Formula to mark X if two values are found

Tags: excel, formula

I have a spreadsheet that lists pieces of equipment with columns for the type of equipment and their city location etc.  Each region (made up of multiple cities) has a sheet for all of their equipment.

I am trying to set up a sheet that summarizes which equipment is located in which city.

I have been trying to set up a formula that will look at Sheet2 and the column for location and the column for the equipment type and if the city matches say Adelaide and also matches Bench Shears then mark with an X.

I have tried using a =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP formula but I can only get it to work with one variable and not 2.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

> > Each region (made up of multiple cities) has a sheet for all of their equipment.

That does not sound like good data architecture. As the golden rule, all your data input should be in ONE sheet. Then you can build reports on that data on other sheets.

With the info you provide above, it looks like a better data structure might be a sheet with a table. The table would have columns for Region, City, Equipment Type.

This is a flat, two-dimensional table. Each piece of equipment goes into its own row. No blank rows, no blank columns. Use Excel's Table feature to make this a table with Ctrl-T.

Now you can create a pivot table. Click a cell in the data table and then Insert ribbon > Pivot table. Drag Region into the Rows area, drag City into the rows area, drag Equipment Type into the rows area and again into the Values area.

[image]

This is a simplified example. If you need more help to get this to work, please edit your question and post a sample file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make a table of the listed values in sheet2, such that cities will be listed in a column and equipment listed in a row, with an x appearing in a cell where the city and equipmnt exist? If so then add a third column to your data in sheet 2:

=A1&B1

for all values in the list, then lookup the two values in each cell in you tabulated data in sheet 1:

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2&B$1...

and use this in all the cells in the table. The dollar signs mean that the column $A and row $1 will not change when you copy the formula across the table.

You need to get all of the data from each region in a single list...